# ASP.NET Core 6 ExceptionMiddleware and Validations

Tags: c#, data-annotations, asp.net-core-3.1, action-filter

In ASP.NET Core 6, I have a custom middleware that handles exceptions returning a specific structure:

```
 services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomHttpResponseExceptionFilter)));
```

Works nicely. However, when an argument fails a param validation like:

```
GetSomethingAsync([Required][MinLength(2)]string orderNumber)
```

the `CustomHttpResponseExceptionFilter` isn't called.

Where can I intercept a failure for e.g. data annotation `[Required]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you need to customize the behavior of [ModelStateInvalidFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.modelstateinvalidfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

To do so, you can achieve that doing the following in your Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        // Expects an instance of IActionResult.
    };
});
```

You will find more information at [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation-failure-error-response).